# Why is my update failing in a each loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
users = User.all()

user.each do |u|

  b = get_id_blah()

  u.some_id = b.id
  u.save

end
```

I get the error:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/activemodel-3.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing': private method `update' called for #<User:0x1017b8188> (NoMethodError)
```

Should I be calling save outside of the loop?

Comment: WHAT? Why are you changing the id?

Comment: the some_id isn't a PK, its something custom (an ID from an external resource on another platform)

Answer (score 2):

This might just be a typo, but it could explain your no-method-error

```
users = User.all()

user**s**.each do |u|


end
```

It should be something like

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  ....
end
```

Or simply

```
User.all.each do |user|
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you this is the exact code? It sounds like you are calling object.update instead of just calling object.save

By the way, you don't need parentheses if you're calling functions in Ruby :-)